# Creating a better JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, coldfusion

I am returning a query object from Coldfusion as a JSON string which I then parse into JSON in Javascript. It has a bit of a strange format when I finally log it though.

I am faced with two problems. First, I do not know how to access the lowest element (i.e Arthur Weasley) as I cannot use a number in my selector (`response.DATA[0].0` doesn't work because the lowest field name is a number). Second, is there any way to assign the values in the columns section to the fields that are numbered 1, 2 and 3?

What I'm really asking is how do I select my lowest level of data? If that can't be done because of the numbers for field names, how do I change the names to something more fitting?

My data logged:

[image]

Comment: As an aside, if you do not like the native query format you can roll your own. Simply build an array of structures and return that instead. For example http://cfsimplicity.com/53/simpler-handling-of-json-serialised-coldfusion-query-objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First entry of first entry of DATA = response.DATA[0][0]

So

```
name = reponse.DATA[0][0];
trainsThing = response.DATA[0][1];
```

Comment: I have tried that, i get the error "Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null"

Comment: Looks like my error was a jquery problem that threw me off course. Thanks